# How to indent a paragraph?

Tags: html, css

On web, paragraph are usually like this:

> Hello, this is a paragraph and I am the writer. My name is Johan Levitt, people calls me Joh (Johan) in short and I have a hobby of creating cool stuffs on Web using dynamic web languages like Javascript, jQuery, PHP, etc.

But I want a paragraph to be like this:

> (space)(space) Hello, this is a paragraph and I am the writer. My name is Johan Levitt, people calls me Joh (Johan) in short and I have a hobby of creating cool stuffs on Web using dynamic web languages like Javascript, jQuery, PHP, etc.

Comment: `p { text-indent: 123em; }` and/or `p:empty + p { text-indent: 0; }`

Answer (score 4):

set the `text-indent` css property. E.g.

```css
p{
   text-indent:50px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try Like this.

```
> <p style="text-indent:30px;">Hello, this is a paragraph and I am the
> writer. My name is Johan Levitt, people calls me Joh (Johan) in short
> and I have a hobby of creating cool stuffs on Web using dynamic web
> languages like Javascript, jQuery, PHP, etc.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `text-indent` CSS property:

```
p { 
    text-indent: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have answered, the [`text-indent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-indent) property in CSS has been designed for such purposes. But most probably you *also* want to suppress default vertical spacing between paragraphs, since first-line indents are normally used *instead of* such separation, not in addition to it.

Assuming your all paragraphs have been marked as `p` elements, you can just add the following to your style sheet:

```
p { text-indent: 1em; margin: 0 }
```

This adds an indent that equals the size of the font. That, or a little more, is common typographic practice. If you want an amount that equals two spaces, the value of `0.5em` is a suitable approximation (the width of a space varies by font, `0.25em` might be regarded as average).

It is common practice to omit the indentation after a heading, which you can achieve by adding

```
h1+p, h2+p, h3+p, h4+p, h5+p, h6+p { text-indent: 0 }
```

Practices differ on the use of indentation after a bulleted list, a table, etc. This is a design issue, but you should probably give it a thought when taking first-line indents into use. An extremistic, but not unrealistic, approach is to use first-line indent only when a paragraph appears after another paragraph; for this, you would *only* use the rule

```
p+p { text-indent: 1em; margin: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a CSS class to indent the paragraph that you want to indent, using `text-indent` otherwise it could effect other paragraphs on the page, like so:

the html:

```
<p class="indented">
    text
</p>
```

and the CSS:

```
.indented{
    text-indent: 50px;
}
```

[EXAMPLE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/lee_gladding/uyPxt/)

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple.

```
   p { 
        text-indent: 3em;
    }
```